# how can i write "" as a value option in html

Tags: html

I am learning how to code through freecodecamp.org. One of the exercises is to write "" as a value of an option element in HTML.

I've tried writing it with this syntax:
<option=""> 
but it's not working.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you forgot the value attribute

```
<option value=""></option>
```